# How to export full content of long table to PDF using Power BI

Tags: pdf, powerbi, export

how to download a complete report in PDF. If the table in the Power BI  dashboard is longer than the display area the PDF will only contain the visible section. The content not visible will not be captured in the exported pdf.

Comment: Verify this article:

https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Community-Blog/How-to-use-Power-BI-Rest-API-to-export-the-Power-BI-Report-in/ba-p/2179741

Comment: How about creating a paginated report and exporting to PDF? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/paginated-reports/paginated-reports-report-builder-power-bi